# Responsive html homepage

Tags: html, responsive-design

Was wondering if there was anyone that could help me with an issue I'm having with the responsiveness of [a page](http://www.imaginationcreation.co.uk/acplc/website2/) that I've created for a client.

Basically I need this design to fully fit the screen (height and width) on all desktop screen sizes without a scroll bar appearing; I know I'm on the right path but cannot find the solution

Any suggestions please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap col-xs

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>   
  </div>
```

**DEMO** http://jsbin.com/pumiteqoji/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Hi Rumit 

Thank you for your solution

My email is jamiedunn1975@gmail.com

Send me yours as I may have some work for you if you are interested

Kind regards

Jamie